# How to remove ADFS server from Azure Domain Controller

Tags: adfs

I have ADFS 2012 R2 installed on a Domain Controller in Azure and I want to remove the role, in fact separate them out. Is it as straight forward as :

1. Installing another ADFS server in the same site to the ADFS farm
2. Removing the ADFS role from the Azure DC?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

The current one is your primary and the DNS (e.g. login.adfs.com) points to it.

The new one will be the secondary so when you remove the old one, you need to promote the new one to primary and switch the DNS over.